# How to type/send values to fast-monaco-editor

Tags: java, selenium

I tried clicking on the field and typing values. Actually the field is getting clicked but its not typing values. I am working on protractor Selenium Java framework. Sharing below the code I used

1. `driver().contextClick(computationText);  driver().type(computationText,addText);`

2    `computationText.click(); computationText.sendKeys(addText);`

here computationText is `"//fast-monaco-editor[@id='computation']//div"`

I tried even executeScript, but not sure how to use it in Selenium

Comment: You can use Protractor with Java? I thought it only supported Javascript and Typescript~

Comment: Anyway, we need more information. Can you share your full code, and the full HTML of the page?

Comment: ```<fast-monaco-editor _ngcontent-dxa-c361="" id="computation" class="sl-form-row-elt-width-stretch" _nghost-dxa-c326=""><div _ngcontent-dxa-c326="" tabindex="0" class="sl-readonly-editor sl-platform-windows sl-readonly-editor-border" style="display: block;"></div><!----></fast-monaco-editor>```  (this is the html code for page)  @C. Peck